# VS Code parentheses autocomplete for arrow functions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, arrow-functions

Is there any way to turn on autocompletion with parentheses for arrow functions?

I already use `javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls`, but it works only for regular functions.

```js
function foo () {
}

const bar = () => {
}

foo();  // autocompleted ()

bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they have different types

```
function foo() : void

const bar: () => void
```

the setting `javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls` seems to work only for the `function` type variables.

Place an issue request at the VSC (JavaScript extension) repo.

The same for Typescript files.

Answer (score -1):

install this extension **Arrow Function Snippets** in your VS code
and simply type `cafe` and press enter, this will generate the whole arrow function for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!